# Android java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my formatting I am newbie to android as well as to stackoverflow
cant submit all of my logcat due to some formatting error

in short I am getting following error:

```
at com.youmasti.mp3test.MainActivity.findsongs(MainActivity.java:45)
at com.youmasti.mp3test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
```

Here is my code:

```
Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
String items;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPlaylist);
    //File fTest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    ArrayList<File> mySongs = findsongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

    for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
        toast(mySongs.get(i).getName().toString());
    }
}

public ArrayList<File> findsongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al= new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] file= root.listFiles();

    for (File singlefile : file) {
        if (singlefile.isDirectory() && !singlefile.isHidden()) {
            al.addAll(findsongs(singlefile));
        } else {
            if (singlefile.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                al.add(singlefile);
            }
        }
    }
    return al;
}

public void toast (String text) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

List item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.youmasti.mp3test">    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
LogCat

   08-30 10:39:30.227    2441-2441/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni        (already on)
   08-30 10:39:30.227    2441-2441/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
   08-30 10:39:30.229    2441-2441/? I/art﹕ JIT created with                code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
   08-30 10:39:30.346    2441-2441/? W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced        unknown path: /data/app/com.youmasti.mp3test-1/lib/x86
   08-30 10:39:30.527    2441-2441/com.youmasti.mp3test D/AndroidRuntime﹕        Shutting down VM
       --------- beginning of crash
   08-30 10:39:30.528    2441-2441/com.youmasti.mp3test E/AndroidRuntime﹕        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.youmasti.mp3test, PID: 2441
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo       {com.youmasti.mp3test/com.youmasti.mp3test.MainActivity}:        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity       (ActivityThread.java:2416)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity                     (ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11                                                        (ActivityThread.java)
               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage       (ActivityThread.java:1344)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run       (ZygoteInit.java:726)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main       (ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of        null array
               at com.youmasti.mp3test.MainActivity.findsongs       (MainActivity.java:45)
               at com.youmasti.mp3test.MainActivity.onCreate       (MainActivity.java:27)
               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate       (Instrumentation.java:1107)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity       (ActivityThread.java:2369)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity       (ActivityThread.java:2476)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo", you don't have that activity declared in manifest

Comment: Have you checked that your ExternalStorageDirectory has files? That's why you are getting `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Looks like File[] file might be null.

Answer (score 11):

You have to point to us where is the line 45.

But I would guess it is this line

```
for (File singlefile : file) {
```

if yes, the problem is because `listFiles()` return `null`

It can return null for several reasons, root not exists, or root is not a folder, or most likely, as you are working with Android, you missed to add the permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**EDIT:**

after your edit, I believe your manifest has some problem

please check a sample here

https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/AndroidManifest.html

**EDIT2:**

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

for android 6.0, you need to request permission

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
    }

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant

    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.Y es 45th line is for (File singlefile : file) {
I have already added that permission in Manifest folder, Please see my manifest in above post.

Comment: Are you testing on android 6.0 emulator? or android 6.0 device?

Comment: when I tested it on 6.0 emulator I gave me above error but I just tried it on my cell phone and it is working fine. how come  ?

Comment: in android 6.0, you need to requestPermission for "dangerous" permission, edited my answer to include the link about **request permission**

Comment: Maybe you could accept the answer, and start a new question if you meet any further problems when implementing request permission

Comment: Derek thanks very much, I will definitely try this now and let you know.

Comment: To clarify: Your code snippet asks for the permission to read contacts? So for SD card access, this has to be adapted to READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (which implies read).

Comment: Thanks @StephanMatthiesen i donn't know that permission is required.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `MainActivity.java:45` is this line:

```
for (File singlefile : file) {
```

It means that `file` is `null`.

According to the javadoc of [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory

So value of `root` is not a path name.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am just trying to scan phone storage to find some file and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()); is that location

Answer (score 0):

your

```
  listFiles()
```

method may return null and
 root is not any path (use as)

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + path like directory name
```